# drools rule flow

Tags: java, rules, drools

I'm having a strange issue with drools :

I have the following rules :

```
rule "is my dog a baby?"
  ruleflow-group "dog"
  salience 10
  when 
     dog : Dog(age <1 )
  then 
     dog.setIsBaby(true);
end


rule "baby dog"
    ruleflow-group "dog"
    salience 9
    when
        myData : MyData( myDog.isBaby() == false)
    then
        System.out.println(myData.getMyDog().getIsBaby());
end
```

I insert in my session myData and `myData.getMyDog()`, where `myData.getMyDog.isBaby==false`

The first rule is fired and my dog is set to be a baby. Then the second one is fired, and even it prints true .(even if the condition was to be false)

And when I test after firing all rules , myDog in myData is set to be a baby .

What am I doing wrong here ? Why does the second rule is fired ? is the problem in the session (stateful in my case) ?

I think that I need to say that I modify myData:myDog somewhere ,but I am not sure where .

Hope my question is clear, if not tell me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you modify working memory facts, you need to tell Drools that the data has changed so it can re-evaluate all relevant rules.

Drools evaluates facts before firing any matched rules. If you have a dog with age = 0 and baby = false, both your rules will be activated. When your `is my dog a baby?` rule is fired, it doesn't change the fact that when Drools evaluated the `baby dog` rule, the `myDog.isBaby() == false` condition was true.

To inform Drools that you have modified some fact, use the `update()` knowledge helper method. Keep in mind that Drools associates fact handles to a specific object. If a rule references `MyData`, and you want that rule to be re-evaluated when the `MyData.myDog` object has changed, you'll need to use `update()` on the `MyData` object; just doing `update()` on your `Dog` object, will not cause the `baby dog` rule to be re-evaluated.

Try changing your `is my dog a baby?` rule to the following:

```
rule "is my dog a baby?"
    ruleflow-group "dog"
    salience 10
    when 
        dog : Dog(age < 1, baby == false)
        myData : MyData(myDog == dog)
    then
        dog.setIsBaby(true);
        update(dog);
        update(myData);
    end
```

Comment: Thx a lot I'm going to try that

Answer (score 9):

You need to do

```
then 
    dog.setIsBaby(true);
    update( dog )
```

on your first rule and rewrite the **when** of your second rule like

```
when
    dog :    Dog( isBaby == false)
    myData : MyData( myDog == dog)
```

The rule has to be written in this way, so drools can automatically detect which rules it has to run again after a fact changes.

Every time you change a fact in the rules engine, you need to tell the working memory that you've changed it with update.

I haven't used drools since version 4, but I assume that this still applies.

Comment: Thx a lot I'm going to try that

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should update both the dog and the map.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can update the dog in working memory by using `modify` or `update` knowledge helper methods. If you can any of the above function Drools will re-evaluate the rules again and you will end up with an infinite loop. so you also need to you no-loop attribute in your rule or modify you condition to

`dog : Dog(age <1, isBaby == false )`

so that the next time it will not evaluate the same rule again and update the isBaby to true again and again.